# Explain PHPNG (next generation) and how to use it

Tags: php, php-7

So I have done a few Google searches and I cannot find an answer to my questions. I noticed PHPNG was in the master in PHP 7.0 so I'm guessing we can use it with the release of PHP 7.0.

My questions are:

- how do we use phpng (specifically with nginx)?
- what should we be using it for (dev, production etc)?
- does anyone even use it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That engine is the core of PHP 7. If you use PHP 7, you're using the newest engine. There's no special setup there, compile PHP 7 and run `php-fpm`. That's it really :) nginx uses fcgi proxy pass to send http requests to the fpm node, classic setup as with php 5.

Comment: ahhh ok, there isn't a huge amount of articles about it hence my n00b question

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a n00b question, it's perfectly valid and we cleared it up now so it's all good :) have a nice day!

Comment: PHPNG was the name of the experimental development branch which made some big internal changes to try and speed up PHP. It was quite effective, so PHP 7 ended up being based on it, and now PHP 7 has been released. So PHPNG is just a relic, now.

Comment: Thanks very much @Andrea